# How Access Parent Activity withou use up button in TabLout

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener, android-tablayout, start-activity

Please i realy want to know how to access parent activity without use Up-Button of TabLayout.
This is the onClickListener set in the Button.

```js
retour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
               //start parent Activity
            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to rewrite your question. it is very unclear as to what you are asking or what you are trying to accomplish. Accessing an activity from a fragment is very easy, but I think you are "Possibly" asking how to use back button to navigate somewhere without overriding back button, but I'm guessing because your question is so ambiguous.

Comment: Done ! 
Yes it is : i want to know how to use back button to navigate somewhere without overriding back button

Comment: you can just call `finish()` on your current activity and it will open previous activity if you have not finished it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all,
this is the correct answer:

```js
        retour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent upIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CurrentActivity.class);
                if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(CurrentActivity.this, upIntent)) {
                    TaskStackBuilder
                            .from(CurrentActivity.this)
                            .addNextIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParentActivity.class))
                            .addNextIntent(upIntent).startActivities();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(CurrentActivity.this, upIntent);
                }
            }
        });
```

I think you can also use "finish()" as mentionned by @Karan_Mer